# Mysterious yet consistent packet loss

Tags: windows-8, packet-loss

A few days ago I started having strange problems with my Internet connection. It disconnected at seemingly random times, and I had to restart my router to bring it back up. I also noticed that it didn't crash when I pulled the UTP cable from the PC I use the most (this doesn't mean I'm certain it can't crash when that PC was disconnected, it just seemed to happen more when it wasn't). I tried switching to a UTP cable with no success.

I thought it was some sort of problem with my router, so I connected another one and now I have a similar, but perhaps even stranger problem: it doesn't completely disconnect me from the Internet (only happened once so far, so might be a coincidence) but I do lose some packets every minute or so. In fact, I'm beginning to think it happens EXACTLY every minute, especially if I believe my `ping -t google.com`. When I keep testing on pingtest.net a few times in a row, at about 1/5th of the tries it has packet loss; that packet loss is ALWAYS exactly 12 packets out of 250(5%).

I also tested my network speed using speedtest.net and Steam downloads, it's a consistent 90-100Mbit download speed and 60-90Mbit upload speed, which is quite normal.

Does anyone know what could be causing this problem? The consistency of it baffles me.

**Some specs of my PC/Network:**

- Router: TP-Link TL-WR1043ND
- Network card: Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
- OS: Windows 8 Pro